# Copy contents of one table into another in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables in rails.. 
pending_products
processed_products

In pending products there's a status field.. 
When a record gets added to the pending table (or updated) the status is set to 1. 
When I want to process I change all the 1's to 2 and then select all the 2's. 
When I'm done with all the records, I change all the 2's to 1000.. (seemed like a nice number to say done).

(If you're wondering why I set to 2, it's so that if a feed comes in while I'm processing it wouldn't update that record, because the status would have been set to 1 by the feed)

Before I change all the 2's to 1000, I want to insert into the processed table.

Now I can do an "insert into" in pure SQL, but I am wondering if there's a rails way to do this.. Something more elegant than raw SQL.

Comment: Why do you need to move anything if you already have a status? And there's not much more elegant, or faster, than raw SQL when dealing with... raw SQL.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you actually modeling different data in `PendingProduct` and `ProcessedProduct`, or do they only differ on the `status` field? It seems weird to have two different models simply because one hasn't been "processed" yet.

Comment: The data in the tables is vastly different. The insert would be the first step in stage two of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
class PendingProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  OUTSTANDING = 1
  PROCESSING = 2
  PROCESSED = 1000

  scope :outstanding, where(status: OUTSTANDING)

  def process
    transaction do
      self.status = PROCESSING
      self.save!

      # do whatever processing you need to do...

      # ...then create your ProcessedProduct record...
      ProcessedProduct.create!( ... )

      # ...and finally update this PendingProduct
      self.status = PROCESSED
      self.save!
    end
  end
end

PendingProduct.outstanding.each(&:process)
```

This is arguably more "elegant" than raw SQL, but it's guaranteed to be slower.

Comment: Yeah.. I can't sacrifice speed for elegance.  Not on this kind of scale. I do like the transaction thing though.. I didn't know you could do that.